# Unable to debug code in debug mode

Tags: python

I have been using Python debug mode quiet frequently except that now I get this issue:

```
-> plt.subplot(221)
(Pdb) can't invoke "event" command:  application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"
```

I tried to search for an answer but nothing is resolving it.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493487/1860929) and also this [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue20567).